# How to have spool file display result of query? (Having trouble)

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to export a .csv file (spool file) that has the result set of a very simple query that I am running in Oracle SQL Developer. The spool file generates; however, only the query is displayed (select * FROM TABLE) with no result set. What am i doing wrong? The command I am using is as follows:

```
spool "C:\Temp\test.csv"

select * from table;

spool off;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use below commands to get the output of the query in spool file

> > **SET SERVEROUTPUT ON**
> >
> > **SET ECHO ON**

After executing the select query don't forget to spool off.

Comment: that doesn't work for me for some reason. can you send me the complete code? I tried that (added it) and am still getting the same issue.

Comment: SET SERVEROUTPUT ON is used for output from PL/SQL blocks. you shouldn't need it in this situation and ECHO ON just echoes the command to the screen/file. This will not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

So i did some more research / experimenting and i found that the following works:

I first created a sql file with the appropriate sql script /command and placed it in a directory (C:\TEMP). Then i ran the following command:

```
SET NEWPAGE 0
SET SPACE 0
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET HEADING OFF
set verify off
SET ECHO OFF
spool "c:\Temp\test.csv"
@c:\Temp\test.sql as script(F5);
spool off
```

However now i run into a road block where oracle throws me an error saying that only 5,000 rows are currently supposed in script results...

Edit: I created the above code as a .sql file (test2.sql) and ran the below script. But am still encountering the 5000 row error:

```
SET NEWPAGE 0
SET SPACE 0
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET HEADING OFF
set verify off
SET ECHO OFF
spool "c:\Temp\test2.csv"
@c:\Temp\test2.sql as script(F5);
spool off
```

The following worked when I tried to increase the limit: I went up to my sql developer tool bar ( tools > prefs > database > worksheet) and was able to change the maximum output limit.

Comment: put all of that in a script and execute in sqldev as @script - the 5,000 row output limit will be ignored. Or go into the preferences and increase the script output limit

Comment: i just tried that, doesn't seem to work. I added/edited what i did to this answer

Comment: nevermind, was able to finagle my way to a solution. thanks a bunch!

Comment: spool prints to a file, if you want to see the file contents add a HOST command and issue a TYPE c:\Temp\test2.csv